# Web Api Error 500

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have got a ajax call through which I am calling my Web Api.My code is as follows-

```
function DataFrame() {

                var abc = {};
                abc.Country = countryName;
                abc.Month = monthName;
                abc.SampleData = selectedStores;
                var datatoSend = JSON.stringify(abc);
                jQuery.support.cors = true;
                $.ajax({
                    url: URL + '/api/Sample/AddSampleToFrame/',
                    type: "Post",
                    data: JSON.stringify(datatoSend),
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    success: function (result) {
                        if (result.length > 0) {
                            _sampletabledata = $.parseJSON(result);
                            PoplulateListSample();
                            PopulateSampleCheckBox();
                            BindSampleGrid();
                            BindBoxesWithSet();
                        }
                    }, //success of ajax

            return false;

}
```

This code is returning **error 500**.Need your suggestions

Comment: Impossible to tell without seeing the code of the server. All 500 codes are because of internal server errors

Comment: The content of the response should contain more information about the error. You can check it with the dev tools for the browser you are using.

Comment: Hookup a debugger to your WebAPI, enable unhandled exceptions, and see what happens.